# Creating a Page of Posts

Tags: posts, pages, page-template

I've been away from Wordpress for a few months, and now I'm struggling to remember how to create a Page of Posts. It's most infuriating!

**The Current Site**

I have `home.php` set up to display the latest Posts of a Custom Post Type as the main page. It works fine. A simple `pre_get_posts` function in `functions.php` sets the CPT to be displayed:

```
$query->set('post_type', 'campaign');
$query->set('posts_per_page', 11);
```

...when `is_home() && $query->is_main_query()`. **This is correct, and does not need to be changed.** It works great, but now the client wants a normal news blog **elsewhere** on the site.

**The New Version**

So... I need to add a news blog, that's not on the homepage, leaving the homepage as it is. It makes sense to me to use the default Post post type for this, and it makes sense for me to create a Page for this. But I can't seem to get a Page of Posts to work.

At first I created a `page-blog.php` template for a "News" Page, but it didn't pull in Posts with `while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();`. Instead it only listed *itself*...?

I then added a new line to my `pre_get_posts` function:

```
if(is_page_template('page-news.php')) {
    $query->set('post_type', 'post');
}
```

But now the page returns 404.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code in your `page-blog.php` to display list of posts

```
$paged = get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',    //Change this with your post type
        'posts_per_page' => 10,  //No. of Pages to show         
        'offset' => 0,   //excluding the latest post if any
        'paged' => $paged  //For Pagination
    );

$loop = new WP_Query( $args );

while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();?>
<h3><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title();?></a></h3>
<?php    the_content(__('Continue Reading'));             
endwhile;

wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: I remember now! Ahhhh...

Answer (score 1):

**Changing the post type on the home page**

By default, WordPress shows the post post type on your home page
To add pages, open your theme’s **functions.php** file and paste this PHP code into it:

```
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_get_posts' );

function my_get_posts( $query ) {

    if ( is_home() && $query->is_main_query() )
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'page', 'album', 'movie' ) );

    return $query;
}
```

Showing the post types in your feed
Realizing that many of you might want to also add these post types to your feed to match your blog, a small change in the code is required. All you need to do is change this line:

```
if ( is_home() && $query->is_main_query() )
```

We’ll use the `is_feed()` conditional tag:

```
if ( ( is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) || is_feed() )
```

Now, you can have custom post types in your regular blog post rotation and your feed.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:post_type=custom_post type slug

```
<?php
    global $paged;  
        if( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) {
            $paged = get_query_var( 'paged' );
        } elseif( get_query_var( 'page' ) ) {
            $paged = get_query_var( 'page' );
        } else {
            $paged = 1;
        }

        $args = array(
            'post_type'     => 'your_post_type',
            'paged'         => $paged,
        );

        $blog_query = new WP_Query($args);
    ?>

    <section>
        <?php if ( $blog_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
        <?php while ( $blog_query->have_posts() ) : $blog_query->the_post(); ?>
        <?php get_template_part( 'content-parts/content', get_post_format() ); ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </section><!-- End #content -->
?>
```